# How to improve the rendering speed with i7 -950 machine and Ge force GTX460

Tags: rendering, performance-tuning

I have a i7- 950, with Geforce GTX460 Graphic Card.  Its a 1 GB Card.  we use 3dsmax for rendering the various scenes.  each frame is taking around 11 minutes.  when the grpahics card is changed to GE FX580 (512MB) or Firepro v4800 (1GB), the performance did not change at all.  How to use the full power of the CPU and GPU.

Answer (score 1):

Unless things have changed, 3dsmax only uses the CPU for rendering. Videocard acceleration only during operation (viewport). Therefore the GPU is not used, and changing it would not make a difference.

Comment: Well there is one thing he could do and that's overclocking the CPU. I think i7-950, with good cooling could hit 4ghz, but I'm not really sure about stability tho.

Answer (score 0):

The first stop should be [NVIDIA Driver Downloads](http://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx?lang=en-us).
This also contains an auto-detect option for finding your best Geforce driver.

Your next step should be to ensure that the rendering software you are using does use multiple threads, or can be configured to use them. As you have 4 multi-threaded cores, 8 threads should be the optimum.